# ARC Objective-C: How can self be deallocated?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, automatic-ref-counting, memory-management

I am creating a workflow to navigate through websites, every step of the workflow has to load n frames and then knows its ready (I have to implement the timeout).

I don't understand why [self next] is giving me this error:
*** -[WebWorkflow next]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x105796ef0**

Considering this delegate function:

```
- (void)webView:(WebView *)sender didFinishLoadForFrame:(WebFrame *)frame {
    frameCounter++;
    NSInteger frames = [(WebWorkflowStep *)[steps objectAtIndex:index] frames];
    NSLog(@"Frame counter %ld of %ld", frameCounter, frames);
    [self next];
}
```

And this next method:

```
-(void) next
{
    if ( index < [steps count])
    {
        frameCounter = 0;
        index = index + 1;
        WebWorkflowStep *step = [steps objectAtIndex:index-1];
        NSDictionary *userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:step forKey:@"selector"];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:EVENT_WORKFLOW_NEXT object:nil userInfo:userInfo];

    }
}
```

Notes:

**- WebWorflow a.k.a 'self' has been created/binded by another class with strong**

Like so:

```
@interface AController : NSObject <APIProtocol>
{
    WebView *webview;
    NSMutableArray *accounts;

    WebWorkflow *workflow;
}

@property (strong) WebWorkflow *workflow;

...
```

I do create the workflow like this:

```
workflow = [[WebWorkflow alloc] initWithWebView:webview];
    NSArray *getPicturesWorkflow = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                            [[WebWorkflowStep alloc] initWithSelector:@"open" andLoadFrames:0],
                                            [[WebWorkflowStep alloc] initWithSelector:@"login" andLoadFrames:2],
                                            [[WebWorkflowStep alloc] initWithSelector:@"getPictures" andLoadFrames:8],
                                             nil];
            [workflow setSteps:getPicturesWorkflow];
```

And it gets initialized like:

```
-(id)initWithWebView:(WebView *)webview
{
    self = [ super init];
    if(self) {
        timeout = 10;
        index = 0;
        web = webview;
        frameCounter = 0;
        [web setFrameLoadDelegate:self];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: I'm sure it's hard to accomplish, but not impossible.  Are you sure that the "owning" object is itself still in existence?

Comment: The most important code to this question is in your note.  Please post the code that "created/binded" the web view.

Comment: Adding the code that created `workflow` and set it as delegate may help. Also, the delegate property is `assign` or `weak` right?

Comment: Is `AController` the `WebView` delegate?

Comment: I think my other comment was confusing.  It's clear what's happening here:  the webview is asynchronously loading web content and messaging it's delegate, but the delegate is being released sometime during the load.  The question is why?  The code we need to see everything that pertains to the memory management of the object set as the WebView delegate.  Please implement dealloc in the WebView's delegate.  NSLog or break point there.

Comment: @danh I updated the question with more code, hope it helps. Thanks for your time. It is not a UIWebView but a WebView for a Desktop App.

Comment: `initWithWebView` refers to an instance variable called `web` but in the `@interface` it's called `webview`?

Comment: @trojanfoe that's the parent/owner interface. They are using the same object, but the only delegate is WebWorkflow.

Comment: Confusing to say the least.

Comment: Do not use arc for the particular file and then manage all the memory within the class yourself. That way you could also use [self release]. Use the compiler flags -fno-objc-arc for all the files that you want to disable arc.

Comment: @insane-36: That sounds like a good way to introduce a lot of other bugs. There's a reason ARC was introduced, and that reason is because it makes most memory-management bugs impossible or at least very difficult to create.

Comment: Yes, indeed but in some scenario, it may come handy. Like in some situations where you would like to release self on certain condition, it is not possible with non arc. But, I could release the self when I certain things go wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The AController instance owns a web view and is the web view's delegate.  The AController instance is getting released (for some reason...we'd need to see how *it's* owner manages it).  Since it might get released during a load, it should clean up after itself as follows:

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [web stopLoading:self];  // or webView, not sure what you call it
}
```

This will prevent the crash.  It will also abandon the load.  If you don't want to do that, you'll need to figure out why the AController instance is being released.

The first step in doing that would be a breakpoint in the dealloc method.

Comment: I finally did solve it. This class had like 3 levels of components above. The top one was deallocated and then there rest of them where deallocated in cascade. I solved the problem debugging and putting a dealloc in each class until I found the root. Is ARC really a good thing? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @XaviColomer: Yes. ARC makes it harder to create memory-management bugs and easier to fix them.

Comment: Glad you solved it.  ARC is big help, but I think it's more valuable after having done a few projects without it, which forced learning objective-c memory management.  If you understand what it's doing for you, ARC is really a good thing.